# Selenium not in path for cronjob

Tags: linux, selenium, cron, debian

I'm trying to set up a cronjob for a script on a Linux/Debian 10 machine on google cloud platform but I'm getting an error about chromedriver not being in PATH:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I'm trying to run the script with this cronjob:

```
30 2 * * * cd /home/scripts/data-pull && /usr/bin/python3 /home/scripts/data-pull/login.py
```

The script uses selenium and if I try to run it with `python 3 login.py`, it works correctly. This is because I've set a variable in the script which identifies where chromedriver is located `CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'`

This means that the issue here is to get the cronjob to find the chromedriver executable when it triggers. How do I do that?

I'd greatly appreciate your help with solving this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Define env variable in the crontab itself

```
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

# m h  dom mon dow   command
30 2 * * * cd /home/scripts/data-pull && /usr/bin/python3 /home/scripts/data-pull/login.py
```

2. Create a bash script that exports the env variable before executes your script. Then use this script in your crontab

```
export CHROMEDRIVER_PATH='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
cd /home/scripts/data-pull && /usr/bin/python3 /home/scripts/data-pull/login.py
```

3. Setting env variable in `/etc/environment`